# Add Custom Controls to MoviePlayer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying to figure out how to add a custom control to the iPhone MoviePlayer.
For an example of what I am trying to do see the following image.

[image]

I am trying to add something like the controls on the right and left of the basic movie controls.

I had done this in the Open SDK by adding a subclass to the playerview, but now in the official SDK and Apple moving to MPMoviePlayerController I am not sure how to do it.

Also with my old 1.x firmware way it required me to capture touch events and hide/show the control myself. I am hoping there is a way that would do this with the standard controls, but if not, that is fine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the BEST way to do this!

You create your movie player like normal and then do the following:

```
id vvController = [theMovie videoViewController];
[[vvController _overlayView] addSubview:mainView];
```

Where 'mainView' is your custom overlay. Doing this makes it so your custom overlay will show and hide with the normal overlays as they are now one in the same!

*Please note that this is still using the standard frameworks, but it is undocumented in the frameworks. So it should be 100% appstore safe, but "could" change without notice from Apple in later frameworks.*

Comment: do you guys happen to know if you can create custom controls other than the ones in the mediaplayer? for example, frame by frame playback?

Comment: You can create controls, but what those controls do is limited to what you can do with the SDK. For example, I have a rating control that I show and when rated it sends it off to a server. What you are wanting would require being able to tell the player to move forward 1 frame and stop, which you cant currently. File a feature request at bugreporter.apple.com if you want it.

Comment: please provide the any sample code for custom video player with own controls

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's in a 'standard framework', it is a *private method*, thus not allowed!

Comment: I realize this worked in 2008, but what about 2013? It's not working for me so I figured I would ask.

Comment: This will get your app rejected.

Answer (score 10):

Folks here have probably also seen in various other blog posts the following approach to  "get the movie-player window" -- at index = 1. Though this approach (see snippet below) is also possibly a bit "fragile", it's likely a bit "safer" since it does *not* make use of any undocumented or non-public methods in MPMoviePlayerController.

Note also that you should wait until you get a MPMoviePlayerContentPreloadDidFinishNotification, so that the movie-player window (idx=1) will indeed exist ;-)

Note I'm also assigning an arbitrary (integer-valued) view "tag" to myOverlayView here -- so that I can re-use the view when possible, i.e. check if it's already been added to the parent player window.

anyhoo, here's the relevant code-snippet:

```
// use slight "hack" to get our (parent) movie-player window, should always (?) be the UIWindow at index = 1
//
UIWindow *moviePlayerWindow= [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];

myOverlayView.center = CGPointMake(
                            moviePlayerWindow.bounds.size.width - (myOverlayView.bounds.size.height / 2) - myOverlayView.display_origin.y,
                            moviePlayerWindow.center.y
                                  ); // center our overlay-view

myOverlayView.hidden = NO; // and show it

if( [moviePlayerWindow viewWithTag: MY_OVERLAY_VIEW_TAG] == nil ) {
    // haven't added our overlay-view as a sub-view to the main MoviePlayer window yet... so do that now
    myOverlayView.tag = MY_OVERLAY_VIEW_TAG;
    [moviePlayerWindow addSubview: myOverlayView];
}
[moviePlayerWindow bringSubviewToFront: myOverlayView]; // in any case, bring it to the foreground
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not interpreting your theory correctly, but my custom control isn't hiding with the rest of the player controls. Is this code supposed to allow for that?

Answer (score 8):

[This sample application](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/MoviePlayer_iPhone/index.html) that Apple provides should help. From the description:

> Demonstrates how to use the Media
>   Player Framework to play a movie
>   full-screen. The sample contains code
>   to configure the movie background
>   color, playback controls and scaling
>   mode via the built-in Settings
>   application. Also shows how to draw
>   custom overlay controls on top of the
>   movie during playback.

Comment: This works for adding a custom control, however it does not toggle with the default controls.

The sample shows how to catch a touch within your own custom control, but what they show you will not work with hiding your control. You will need to still catch other taps to be able to hide your control.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend VideoPlayerKit. Supports streaming, fullscreen, AirPlay.

https://github.com/ign/VideoPlayerKit

Comment: I have been having trouble with using this, more specifically with the "ShareThis" part of the code. Heres a question i posted before. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667078/are-there-any-tutorials-on-setting-up-videoplayerkit

Answer (score 1):

I have not implemented ALMoviePlayerController but it seems to provide a succinct and sufficient solution to your problem.

From git repo:

"A drop-in replacement for MPMoviePlayerController that exposes the UI elements and allows for maximum customization"

https://github.com/alobi/ALMoviePlayerController