# Add custom control to MoviePlayer

Tags: objective-c, ios

I need to add a share button to MoviePlayer, that appear and disappear at the same time when touching the screen like and with native controls.

i found this solution:

[Add Custom Controls to MoviePlayer in iPhone 3.0 SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240524/add-custom-controls-to-movieplayer-in-iphone-3-0-sdk?lq=1)

But  _overlayView property is not recognized with IOS5. Is it possible to achieve it with current SDK?

Thanks.

Comment: What about MPMoviePlayerController.view?

Comment: I have done it, but it doesn't fade away with MoviePlayer controls. Thanks.