# Reduce/remove buffer lag on <video> element (iOS)

Tags: ios, html, video, html5-video

We have an FFMPEG stream being streamed to mobile devices. We're using the HTML5 `<video src="..." webkit-playsinline>` tag to display the video inline (inside a real-time streaming app). We've managed to reduce the delay at the FFMPEG end down to the minimum but there's still a lag at the iOS end, where the player presumably buffers for a couple of seconds.

Is there any way to reduce the client-side delay?

We need as close to real-time as possible and skipping is acceptable.

Comment: you're probably going to have to roll your own using MediaSource - http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/11/Stream-video-using-the-MediaSource-API - as the <video> element is always going to try and buffer and there's no control over that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using an HTML5 video tag then the iOS device will use Quicktime to playback the video. Apple offers no control over internal mechanism like buffer settings for its Quicktime player. For a project on Apple TV I even work with a guy in Cupertino at Apple and they just won't allow any access to the information you would require on their device.

Typically if you use [HLS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/networkinginternet/conceptual/streamingmediaguide/FrequentlyAskedQuestions/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.html):

> Is this a real-time delivery system?
>
> No. It has inherent latency corresponding to the size and duration of the media files containing stream segments. At least one segment must fully download before it can be viewed by the client, and two may be required to ensure seamless transitions between segments. In addition, the encoder and segmenter must create a file from the input; the duration of this file is the minimum latency before media is available for download. Typical latency with recommended settings is in the neighborhood of 30 seconds.
>
> What is the latency?
>
> Approximately 30 seconds, with recommended settings. See question #15.

For live streaming scenario on iOS you better off tuning the streaming chain before the actual player:
capture -> transcoding -> upload -> streaming server -> delivery -> playback

Using ffmpeg you can tune for [zero lantency streaming](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide) at transcoding level which I understand you have done. After that using a well established streaming server like Wowza and CDN delivery will help you get there (of course at a certain cost - and assuming you need a streaming server which you may not).

If you go all native for your iOS app you may look at [MPMoviePlayerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190493/add-custom-controls-to-movieplayer). I have no experience with native app code in iOS so I let you decide if it is worth the time (still I doubt it will be possible because of the underlying Quicktime/HLS layer).

I also came across [this](https://www.npmjs.org/package/hls-buffer) which sounds interesting but I have not tested it and even with such an approach you will face limitations.

Even if it may not be the answer you were looking for I hope this helps.